# Scaling any document to A4 format

Tags: pdf, command-line-interface, ghostscript

I have got some pdf documents that need to be printed to A4 paper.

I know there are options in my pdf reader (evince) to scale the document to fit the exact paper size it's printed to, and that works fine with printing to a file, too.

So there must be a CLI-solution to get this job done, right?

Whenever I want a pdf to be 2 pages on one sheet, I use

```
pdfnup in.pdf --nup 2x1 --outfile out.pdf
```

But that doesn't work – in.pdf is not scaled to fit, instead it's too tiny compared to the output of evince printed to a file. So how can I scale it before (or while) using pdfnup? It would be great if that worked for any input format, not just for A5. Thanks in advance for any answer!

Regards, LDer

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, I just figured something out on my own. Sorry for bothering anyone!

```
gs -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 in.pdf
```